# How to recreate this collapse and move to the background UITableViewCell effect? Gif inside

Tags: swift, xcode, uitableview

I googled a lot about collapsing UITableViewCell, but did not found anything. How can I recreate this effect on the first cell ("Wetter"), when moving the view? It will collapse and then move to the background.

[image]